# Why does watcher trigger twice?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using vue-material.io, the datepicker particularly.

But I've got a problem during state observation.

The watcher triggers twice. Is this a package bug or vue's nature?

**How to reproduce:**

Try to select a date and see console.

You can see it triggers twice unexpectedly.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-material-basic-example-hxzwp

Answer (score 1):

I think this has to do with a watcher inside the component. If you change the date by clicking it, it sets the data and emits it. Then the internal watcher kicks in and also changes the data by formatting it and emits the value again. This way you watcher gets triggered twice.

The behaviour can feel strange but it's correct.

If you want you can check out the source code here:
https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material/blob/dev/src/components/MdDatepicker/MdDatepicker.vue

Comment: do you have any solution over this?

Comment: Depends a bit on what you want to do with the value.

Comment: i just want the watcher to be triggered once

Comment: You could add a debouncer in the watcher function (ex: https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) but depending on what you want to do with the value you could also use computed properies from vue

Comment: just tried on local pc, it still triggers twice while using computed.

Comment: I'll make a snippet...moment please

Comment: okay thanks. anyway, you can fork the included sandbox to play it over to solve this problem once and for all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197334/discussion-between-keyboard-ninja-and-mending3).

Answer (score 0):

You can compare oldVal and newVal and only perform event when value changes

```
  watch: {
    selectedDate(newVal, oldVal) {
      if (!newVal || !oldVal || newVal.getTime() !== oldVal.getTime()) {
        console.log(`this is ${newVal}`);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: this still logs twice every time the newval is null

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check with:

```
if (!newVal || `${newVal.getHours()}${newVal.getMinutes()}${newVal.getSeconds()}` === '000') {
    // your code here
    console.log(`this is ${newVal}`);
}
```

Comment: this logs 3 times actually, got even worse as it happens

Comment: Really? The upper codesandbox logs only once to me.

Comment: i've updated the sandbox. you'll find out the problem